# How to update TextView each day even when application not running?

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

let's say I have a simple day counter application, I have a number and for each day that number is incremented by 1 and when the user closes the application the state is saved.

I want the application to store data on file, so no database included

Comment: You can create database or run service in your background project with database

Comment: use `Calender` class with `SharedPreference`

Comment: You can write data to file with proper format when the app close and you can read back when open and you can show the count based on the difference.

Comment: you can create logic for day count from present day using the `Calender` class and then update accrodingly to file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `SharedPreference` to save the current date, and count variable,
each time the app check the number of days difference and add to the count variable updating the `SharedPreference` value in above given current date and variable

lets say,

value saved in `SharedPreference`

```
count = system date - current date;
current date = system date;
```

when you open the app after say 5 days

```
count = systemdate - current date (which was 18-08-2018);

current date = system date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the number each day indifferently if the user opens the app or no, you could to this:

First time user launch the app, you get the current Date (for example using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html))

```
Datetime myTime = DateTime.now()
```

and you store it somewhere, like `SharedPreferences` or [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) database.

Then, each time you need to show the number, you get the Date from where you stored it (Database or SharedPreferences) and calculate the difference with the current Date, like this :

```
 Days days = Days.daysBetween(myTime , DateTime.now());
 int number = days.getDays();
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep Simplicity in this Code I have Used Shared Pereferences to store data and Milli seconds for dates.

```
   int yourNumber = 0;
        SharedPreferences save_data = getSharedPreferences("app", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor save_edit = getSharedPreferences("app", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();


        int days = save_data.getInt("days", -1);//Get Days from the preferences


        if (days < yourNumber) {
            //opened first time; no saved data found ;so save the initial data
            save_edit.putLong("date", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
            save_edit.putInt("days", yourNumber);
            save_edit.commit();
        } else {
            //Already saved data found;
            long oneDayInMilliSeconds = 86400000L;
            long old_date = save_data.getLong("date", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
            long current_date = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            long difference = (old_date + oneDayInMilliSeconds) - current_date;
            if (difference > 0) {
                //One Day Passed; Add One To previous Saved Days


                save_edit.putInt("days", save_data.getInt("days", 0) + 1);//Get Days
                save_edit.putLong("date", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());//update the date
                save_edit.commit();
            }
        }
```